# netdevice notifier

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm adding a netdevice notifier in my module:

```
int os_netdevice_notifier_cb (struct notifier_block *, unsigned long, void *);
...
static struct notifier_block os_netdevice_notifier =
  {
     os_netdevice_notifier_cb,
     NULL,
     0
  };
register_netdevice_notifier(&os_netdevice_notifier);
```

What I want to be able to see is what devices have been registered/unregistered, i.e. I have to monitor event NETDEV_UNREGISTER. Upon receiving this event, is it guaranteed that the device has been removed form the system or this only indicates that it's been scheduled for removing and actual work will be done later?

Looking at the code in net/core/dev.c looks like the event is sent right after the device is cleaned up, but may be I'm missing something?

And the second question -- where is the code that deletes IP/hw addresses assigned to the interface as it's unregistered from the system?

Thanks !
Mark

Answer (score 1):

The device is not totally removed from system at the point of NETDEV_UNREGISTER, at least the ref count is still not zero at that point. The device is already shutdown at least, so it is okay to use NETDEV_UNREGISTER here, as RTM_DELLINK is sent out to user-space at this point too.

The deletion of an IP address is done by inet_del_ifa() in net/ipv4/devinet.c. When unregistering a network interface, upon NETDEV_UNREGISTER event, inetdev_destroy() is called:

```
static void inetdev_destroy(struct in_device *in_dev)
{
        struct in_ifaddr *ifa;
        struct net_device *dev;

        ASSERT_RTNL();

        dev = in_dev->dev;

        in_dev->dead = 1;

        ip_mc_destroy_dev(in_dev);

        while ((ifa = in_dev->ifa_list) != NULL) {
                inet_del_ifa(in_dev, &in_dev->ifa_list, 0);
                inet_free_ifa(ifa);
        }

        RCU_INIT_POINTER(dev->ip_ptr, NULL);

        devinet_sysctl_unregister(in_dev);
        neigh_parms_release(&arp_tbl, in_dev->arp_parms);
        arp_ifdown(dev);

        call_rcu(&in_dev->rcu_head, in_dev_rcu_put);
}
```